# Python: convert \xhh to character

Tags: python, string

I have text in the following form:

```
"\x91It will have to be paid for,\x92 they said. \x91It isn\x92t natural, and\ntrouble will come of it!"
```

I want to convert it to:

```
"'It will have to be paid for,' they said. 'It isn't natural, and\ntrouble will come of it!"
```

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the problem you are having. Please describe both the expected and actual output of that program. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information about how to construct effective sample programs.

Comment: If the original source is XML or HTML there are likely high level libraries or packages that you should use.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = r"\x91It will have to be paid for,\x92 they said. \x91It isn\x92t natural, and\ntrouble will come of it!"
print data.replace('\\x91',"'").replace('\\x92',"'")
```

Answer (score 0):

`\x91` means `LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` and `\x92` means `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` in code page 1252.

you can get the original text by:

```
text = "\x91It will have to be paid for,\x92 they said. \x91It isn\x92t natural, and\ntrouble will come of it!"
print unicode(text, 'cp1252')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode)

```
>>> unidecode.unidecode("\x91It will have to be paid for,\x92 they said. \x91It isn\x92t natural, and\ntrouble will come of it!".decode('cp1252'))
"'It will have to be paid for,' they said. 'It isn't natural, and\ntrouble will come of it!"
```